# Trying to access SFB through APIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, skype-for-business

I am trying to send and receive messages to/from SFB (Skype for business) through UCWA web apis but facing access denied issue.

1) I created Azure AD application.

2) I am able to login successfully and fetching access token and refresh token.

3) But when i try to auto-discover with the above access token, it is giving **403 access denied error**. Please see the request in the code below.

Is it because of SFB deprecation or something else? Please help.

```
let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://webdirin1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscoverservice.svc/root/oauth/user',
    headers:
    {
      accept: 'application/json',
      'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'access-control-allow-origin':'*',
      cors:true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      'x-ms-diagnostic': `PNQIN100EDG08.infra.lync.com`,
      'x-ms-origin': `MAAIN100EDG03.infra.lync.com`,
      authorization: `Bearer ${users[0].access_token}`
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, 403 means you have provided the wrong access token.

Please refer to [Requesting an access token using implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread#requesting-an-access-token-using-implicit-grant-flow).

Note: It seems that the request in the official example is incomplete, you can refer to mine:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant ID}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&client_id={Client ID}&redirect_uri={Reply URL}&state=8f0f4eff-360f-4c50-acf0-99cf8174a58b&resource=https://webdirXX.online.lync.com&nonce=12434152345
```

Modify the above string based on your need and put it directly into the browser for access and log in with your admin account. The access token will be included in the string returned in the address bar.

At last, you could use the access token to call 
`Get https://webdirXX.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user`.

Comment: I tried your url in the browser and logged in with admin account. But it is still giving me error.  **AADSTS500014: Resource 'webdirin1.online.lync.com' is disabled.**  I tried with **webdirXX** also but same error.

Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/oAexIgK

Comment: Could you please provide me with your URL? And which account are you using?

Comment: url which you had mentioned above one only we are using
**https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant ID}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&client_id={Client ID}&redirect_uri={Reply URL}&state=8f0f4eff-360f-4c50-acf0-99cf8174a58b&resource=https://webdirXX.online.lync.com&nonce=12434152345** and we are using microsoft Azure AD

Comment: Please retry GET https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root to get a new webdirXX.online.lync.com and use the new one as the Resource.

Comment: I had tried autodiscovery and getting url which is **https://webdirin1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root**
but when i am using this webdirin1 in the login url for resource key getting error **AADSTS500014: Resource 'https://webdirin1.online.lync.com' is disabled.**

Comment: If you access webdirin1.online.lync.com with a browser, what will you see?

Comment: yeah i had tried with webdirin1.lync.com in browser. Getting this error. **AADSTS500014: Resource 'webdirin1.online.lync.com' is disabled.**
please refer the image also  https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502085204054

Comment: If so, all the requests to this endpoint "webdirin1.online.lync.com" should have be unavailable from your side. But I can access to it. So you could retry with another net environment.

Comment: I did try from different networks. But always got the same error as mentioned above. Azure support guys tell me that UCWA does not work anymore after June 30. And that i have to use MS team. Could that be the issue? Please help.

Comment: I have no idea about the retirement date of UCWA. But I believe that the information provided by Azure support engineer should be authoritative. I can't tell if this is the cause of the error you encountered because it works fine on my side. Besides, Skype for Business Online end of life date is July 31, 2021.

Comment: I had created Azure AD application few days before. Is there any reason that SFB web api will not support for new application?

Comment: I also registered a new application for testing and it works fine. I don't think it's the reason. As I can access "webdirin1.online.lync.com", it is most likely caused by the network.

Comment: I had tried with different network. But getting the error resources is denied

Comment: can you share a documentation that you are following for creating a application, manifest and getting permissions in azure AD

Comment: I just followed this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread#requesting-an-access-token-using-implicit-grant-flow, which has been mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I had also following a same document which you had mentioned. But facing a error while requesting autodiscover with access token. When I look into deep inside the error in headers I had seen 'service doesn't allow cross domain from this domain'.  Is it related to CORS?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any CORS issues? 
check in the response header if you see something like : "Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin."
Refer: https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/itadmin-configuration